# NAs in classCenter function of the R randomForest package

Tags: r, random-forest, na

I am trying to retrieve class prototypes for a two-class classification problem using the `randomForest` package version 4.6-7 for the `R` programming language version 2.13.1. For this, I call the `classCenter` function. The problem is that it sometimes outputs an invalid result, i.e., one or both of the returned class prototypes consist entirely of `NA` values. When this happens, I get the following in the R console:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Typing `warnings()` gives the following 50 times:

```
1: In mean.default(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half +  ... :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

IMPORTANT: I have noticed that the function gives a different output for different random forest models learned on the same data and using the same settings, i.e., it may return both class prototypes for one, but none for another model. That means that at least sometimes I get valid results.

I use this code in the R console:

```
library(randomForest)
mydata <- read.csv("mydata.csv", header=TRUE)
myrf <- randomForest(x=mydata[,-1:-2], y=mydata[,1], ntree=1000, mtry=33, importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE)
mycc <- classCenter(mydata[,-1:-2], mydata[,1], myrf$prox)
print(mycc)
```

The first column of the CSV file contains the class labels, the second one is ignored. There are 5,000 examples of positive and 5,000 examples of negative class, all with 135 features/variables, no missing values (see below).

I have searched on stackoverflow and google for a solution to this problem, but to no avail. The [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) for the `randomForest` package doesn't specify the "all-NAs" return value. I have to say that I'm not familiar with R and have hacked this piece of code using documentation and intuition.

EDIT: `mydata[!complete.cases(mydata),]` is empty, i.e., there are no missing (NA) values in the input data. The output of `summary(mydata)` and `mydata[1:10,]` can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByiDcbjWwz4teXJObm84bkl4R3c&usp=sharing) (you might want to view the file in a text editor without word wrap as the text is formatted wide). The first 10 rows are, of course, not enough to reproduce the error, but I'm not allowed to post the entire dataset.

Comment: Could you supply a subset of the data you use, that can be used to reproduce the error? Otherwise it is very hard to diagnose it. The output of `summary(mydata)` would also be handy to have, since I expect that's where the problem is.

Comment: EDIT: You can find the output of ``summary(mydata)`` and ``mydata[1:10,]`` [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByiDcbjWwz4teXJObm84bkl4R3c&usp=sharing) (you might want to view the file in a text editor without word wrap as the text is formatted wide). The first 10 rows are, of course, not enough to reproduce the error, but I'm not allowed to post the entire dataset. How is it possible to have a class prototype which consists of NAs for some models, and for others not? How do I find out if some of my values are not numeric or logical? ``mydata[!complete.cases(mydata),]`` is empty.

Comment: The data look fine, I just wanted to double check. A long shot idea is that there could be some strange attribute or structure hidden in your data frame that mess things up. Try converting it to a numeric matrix, to remove everything but the raw numbers and the dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem, got rid of it today.
You can do couple of things 
(1) Please drop the column having null values or NA values OR 
(2) Remove the rows with null values or NA values OR
(3) Replace the null or NA values in all columns with appropriate treatment like average, median or mode values (if feasible).Thanks

Comment: ``mydata[!complete.cases(mydata),]`` is empty, i.e., there are no missing (NA) values in the input data.